# How to find the Frobenius series solution of $\cos x~y''+xy'+by=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the equation in series form

$$
\cos{x}~y''+xy'+by=0
$$

where b is a real constant?

---

Here is what I tried:

$$
\cos{x}=\sum_{m=0}\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{(2m)!}
$$
$$
y=\sum_{n=0}a_nx^{n+s}
$$

substitute into the equation we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}\left\{\sum_{m=0}a_n\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m)!}(n+s)(n+s-1)x^{n+s+2m-2}+a_n(n+s+b)x^{n+s}\right\}=0
$$

When $m=n=0$ the $x^{s-2}$ term vanishes, so

$$
s(s-1)=0
$$

$s=0$ or $s=1$

When $m=0,n=1$, the $x^{s-1}$ also vanishes, so

$$
a_1s(s+1)=0
$$

If s=1, then $a_1=0$, the recurrence relationship is

$$
a_n=-\frac{1}{n+1+b}\sum_{m=1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k-2m+2}\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m)!}(k-2m+3)(k-2m+2)
$$

After that I don't know how to solve for each $a_n$.

Comment: Note that when you solve the 2nd order linear ODE of the form other than $(x+k)^2(a_1(x+k)^n+a_2)y''+(x+k)(b_1(x+k)^n+b_2)y'+(c_1(x+k)^n+c_2)y=0$ directly by power series method or frobenius method approach, you should expect you cannot find all of the coefficients most nicely in most cases.